# jQuery - can I animate addClass/removeClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass

Is there anyway to do this rather than animate the css properties individually?

Comment: on newer browser you could delegate CSS to make the animation applied to a particular class

Answer (score 3):

You could use the jQuery UI effects class api:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions

Here do you find more about class transitions.

there is a method called switchClass

> **switchClass**
>
> The switchClass method allows you to visually transition from one
>   class to another. (This functionality is often described as
>   'animateClass'.)

How to use it ? (example from the page itself)

```
$(elem).switchClass('currentClass','newClass',500,'easeOutBounce',function(){
  console.log('transition is done!');
});
```